# Inverse function

Tags: polynomials, inverse

Do you know how I could compute the inverse function of the following polynomial on $[0,1]$?

$f(x)=\alpha x^3-2\alpha x^2+(\alpha+1) x$

(where $\alpha$ is within $]0,3[$)

Comment: What is the domain? How do we know if is injective? We cannot find the inverse unless we know the domain.

Comment: Cubics have three roots. You haven't given enough information for us to be able to pick which of the three are needed.

Comment: The domain is $[0,1]$. $\alpha$ is smaller than 3, which ensure the bijection on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ nonnegative?

Comment: $\alpha$ is within $]0,3[$

Comment: Assuming I am not wrong, it must be $\geq -1$. Otherwise the roots are: $0, 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\alpha|}}, 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\alpha|}}$ (two of them in $[0,1]$). For $-1 \leq \alpha \lt 0$ it is OK, because the derivative is nonnegative in at least (taken for $\alpha = -1$) $[0,4/3]$.

EDIT: OK, $[0,3]$ is even better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

J.M. is right - in general there is no inverse function, because your function is not injective.

I assume that the domain is real numbers.

However, we can check *when* it is not injective. If it is monotonic, then it is injective (since it is a polynomial so it does not have a constant fragments unless it is a constant function - a polynomial of degree 0). And if a polynomial is monotonic, then its derivative is nonpositive or nonnegative. On the other hand if its derivative takes values of both signs, then it is not injective (it first go down from some value, then there is minimum, and then it goes up - a U-shaped function is obviously not injective; the same for first going up and then down).

So we calculate the derivative $3\alpha x^2 - 4 \alpha x + \alpha + 1$. It takes values of both signs if it has two distinct roots, so when the $\Delta$ is positive. $$\Delta = 16\alpha^2 - 4 (\alpha+1)3\alpha = 16\alpha^2 - 12\alpha^2 - 12\alpha = 4\alpha^2 - 12\alpha= 4\alpha(\alpha-3)$$ so it is positive for all $\alpha \in [-\infty,0)\cup(3,\infty]$.

So the task have sense only for $\alpha \in [0,3]$ (assuming $x$ is real, otherwise [in the case of $\mathbb{C}$] the function is not injective for $\alpha \neq 0$).

When you want to calculate $f^{-1}(y)$ you want to find $x$ such that $y=f(x)$, so you're solving the equation: $$\alpha x^3-2\alpha x^2+(\alpha+1) x - y =0.$$ There are different formulas for that on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function). You can ask [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20f%28x%29=%5Calpha%20x%5E3-2%5Calpha%20x%5E2%2b%28%5Calpha%2b1%29%20x) for help, too.